# Is it possible to know what to multiply with a binary number so the answer contains a string of 1's?

Tags: recursion, binary

Is it possible to know what to multiply with a binary number so the answer contains a string of 1's (in binary)?

e.g. 17 * x = 10001 * x = 1111.....
sol: 17 * 15 = 10001 * 1111 = 1111111

e.g. 11 * x = 1011 * x = 1111.....
sol: 11 * 93 = 10001 * 1011101= 1111111111

is it possible to somehow know the value of x without checking every possible value?

edit: the initial no, which needs to be multiplied has will always be odd!

Comment: Do you know about congruences and Euler-Fermat's theorem?

Comment: If $n$ is an odd natural number, the binary representation of $\frac{1}{n}$ is periodic and its period provides an answer to your question, since $1_2 = 0.11111\ldots_2$, just like $1=0.99999\ldots$.

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry! the number will always be odd! so 2 shouldn't be a problem!

Comment: Fermat's little theorem and congruence yeah! @ajotatxe

Comment: i am sorry i am really bad at this, could you explain a bit? @JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly easy to get a formula that works all the time, except that it may not always give you the smallest multiplier.

Let's say you have an odd number $y$. Then it is coprime with $2$, which, by Euler's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) means that $y\mid 2^{\varphi(y)}-1$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function ($\varphi(y)$ is the number of all numbers in the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, y-1\}$ coprime with $y$).

So, you can take $x=\frac{2^{\varphi(y)}-1}{y}$ and note that $2^{\varphi(y)}-1$ has all-ones in its binary representation.

As I said, this won't always give you the smallest number $x$. For example, $y=17$ gives you $\varphi(y)=16$ and so $x=\frac{2^{16}-1}{17}=3855$. For the other example you've given, $y=11$, $\varphi(y)=10$ and $x=\frac{2^{10}-1}{11}=93$.

Comment: φ(y) is easy to calculate for prime numbers, however would still require large no of iterations if y is composite.

Comment: Agreed this is not very efficient. For completeness, the formula for $\varphi(y)$ is: if $y=p_1^{n_1}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$ then $\varphi(y)=p_1^{n_1-1}(p_1-1)\cdots p_k^{n_k-1}(p_k-1)$, so you would need to factorise $y$. Which is the problem a lot of people are working on trying to speed up for large (e.g. 4096-bit large) numbers ;).

Comment: :( factorization would again be NP hard! Though the answer is much appreciated!

Comment: It would be an interesting question whether what you are asking is, in a sense, equivalent to factorisation; say, you choose $N=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are unknown primes; if you can find $x$ such that $Nx$ is all-ones in binary - does it give you any information about $p$ and $q$? Disclaimer: I don't know the answer.

Comment: looks like you can!
https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf

Answer (score 1):

So you are asking if for every $a$ there is a $b$ and $n$ such that:

$$a\cdot b = \underbrace{11...1}_n= {10^n-1\over 9}$$

So for each $a$ we are searching $n$ such that $9a|10^n-1$. We can do this by pigeonhole principle if $gcd(a,10)=1$:

Take a sequence $a_k = 10^k-1$ for $k\in \{1,2,3,...9a,9a+1\}$. Among them there are two that are having the same reminder modulo $9a$, so $$a_i\equiv a_j \pmod {9a}$$ We can assume $j>i$ so $$ 9a\mid (10^j-1)-(10^i-1) = 10^i(10^{j-i}-1)$$
Say $n=j-i$. Since $gcd(10,9a)=1$ we have by Euclid lemma:
$$ 9a\mid 10^n-1$$
and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

**First way**:

- This is possible if and only if $x$ is odd.
- Divide, using binary notation, $1/x$. You should get a periodic number. Let $p$ be the *minimal* period and $n$ its length.
- Write it in the language of series: $$\frac1x=p\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^{nk}}=\frac p{2^n\left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right)}=\frac p{2^n-1}$$
- Now you have
  $$px=2^n-1$$

**Second way**:

If you know about Euler-Fermat's theorem (LFT is not enough), this solution is simpler:

If $x$ is odd, then $\gcd(x,2)=1$. Then $2^{\varphi(x)}\equiv 1\pmod x$. That is, $x$ divides $2^{\varphi(x)}-1$. (Note that $x$ could divide $2^t-1$ for smaller values of $t$). So you just compute 
$$\frac{2^{\varphi(x)}-1}x$$

**Conclusion**:

The fisrt method is slower but it yields the least possible solution, and the second one one can yield a much bigger solution, but it is much faster. The value of $n$ in the first period must divide $\varphi(x)$.

Comment: First way: What about those numbers that aren't periodic? e.g. 1/3233

Comment: It must be periodic (otherwise it would be an irrational number). The period may be **long**, though...